# Who is this white-haired girl figurine wearing a black-and-white grid skirt?

Tags: merchandise

[image]

What anime is this character from? Or what is their name?

Comment: Welcome to Anime & Manga Stack Exchange. While [we accept some kinds of identification request](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4189) (including merchandise such as figurine), please provide [more context](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4142) (e.g. why do you think it's from an anime? Was it bought from a toy/comic/manga/anime store, or a comic convention? etc.) by [edit]ing the question to pass the minimum effort. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It is a Nendoroid of Miss Monochrome, see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miss_Monochrome, which was an original character that was a 3D virtual singer, though she has since appeared in her own anime also named Miss Monochrome.